# Standardizing a set of columns in a pandas dataframe with sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, standardized

I have a table with four columns: CustomerID, Recency, Frequency and Revenue.
[image: My table]

I need to standardize (scale) the columns Recency, Frequency and Revenue and save the column CustomerID.

I used this code:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize, StandardScaler
df.set_index('CustomerID', inplace = True)
standard_scaler = StandardScaler()
df = standard_scaler.fit_transform(df)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = df, columns = ['Recency', 'Frequency','Revenue'])
```

But the result is a table without the column CustomerID. Is there any way to get a table with the corresponding CustomerID and the scaled columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fit_transform` [returns an ndarray](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit_transform) with no indices, so you are losing the index you set on `df.set_index('CustomerID', inplace = True)`.

Instead of doing this, you can simply take the subset of columns you need to transform, pass them to `StandardScaler`, and overwrite the original columns.

```py
# Subset of columns to transform
cols = ['Recency','Frequency','Revenue']

# Overwrite old columns with transformed columns
df[cols] = StandardScaler.fit_transform(df[cols])
```

This way, you leave `CustomerID` completely unchanged.

Comment: Thank you Arturo!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scale` to standardize specific columns:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
cols = ['Recency', 'Frequency', 'Revenue']
df[cols] = scale(df[cols])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this metod:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
df[:, 3:] = sc.fit_transform(df[:, 1:])
```